# In Xamarin Android application how do you list files and open a file using Microsoft Graph API logging into Onedrive?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating a Android application using Xamarin. It will pull a csv file from one drive and display in excel style format grid. I completed the following tutorial:

Build Xamarin apps with Microsoft Graph: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/xamarin
microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-xamarin: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-xamarin

```
This step Get calendar data works fine and shows my calendar appointments but need to list files and open one.
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Thanks, not helpful to me. I modified the Calandarpage.xaml and Calandarpage.xaml.cs trying to see if that works. I have granted the scope to app to read files

Comment: Also have looked at Working with files in Microsoft Graph
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0 this helps but not much

Comment: What specifically have you tried and what specifically does not work?  It's really hard to respond to "this helps but not much"

Comment: The tutorial i completed shows the items of the calandar so i tried  // Get the events
            var events = await App.GraphClient.Me.Events.Request()
                .Select("name,size,createdDateTime")
                .OrderBy("createdDateTime DESC")
                .GetAsync();

Comment: if you don't have permissions to edit yet, you might try deleting the question and asking a new one that includes more detail

Comment: Your question is about retrieving files, but the code you are posting is for events

Comment: Using the graph explorer is a good way to test requests and see samples for different types of requests (You need to sign in with an account that uses O365): https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: I get error Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException
  Message=Code: RequestBroker--ParseUri
Message: Could not find a property named 'name' on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Event'.